# Cassandra Spring-data Multitenancy

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, query-builder, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

So, I'm about to integrate the Multitenancy (one keyspace per tenant) aspect with spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive, I tried to find a solution to access into the right keyspace and I found this approach of using the query-builder:

```
Select select = QueryBuilder.select().from(tenantId,"counter");
select.where(QueryBuilder.eq("id", 1));
Mono<Counter> flux = reactiveCassandraOperations.selectOne(select.toString(), Counter.class);
```

I found it costly in term of development time, especially if we have an insert request ..
Within your experience is there a practical solution where I can insert the keyspace name with the using of the ReactiveCassandraRepository methods ( save, update, findById ..)

Can you support please and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a Cassandra or Spring expert but I am told that you should use ReactiveCqlTemplate (or ReactiveCqlOperations) rather than ReactiveCassandraTemplate (or ReactiveCassandraOperations). See this link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/issues/1218 and follow the links in this page.

From the link, you may get the CqlOperations fronm the CassandraTemplate as follows

```
private final ReactiveCqlOperations cqlOps;
private final YourRepository repository;

@Autowired
public YourService(YourRepository repository, ReactiveCassandraTemplate reactiveCassandraTemplate){
    this.repository = repository;
    this.cqlOps = reactiveCassandraTemplate.getReactiveCqlOperations();
}
```

And then in your repository

```
public interface YourRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<YourData, Long> {

default Flux<YourData> getCQL(ReactiveCqlOperations cqlOps, YourData yourData) {
    return cqlOps.query("SELECT * FROM genericdatadb.YourData WHERE val0 = ? AND val1 = ?;",
            YourRepository.YourDataMapper.INSTANCE,
            yourData.getVal0(),
            yourData.getVal1());
}
```

In the query genericdatadb is the keyspace and YourData is the table. From here, you can add a '?' where genericdatadb is or use a String.format statement to create the query String. Maybe there are Cassandra experts with better solutions?